# Array Modifier not correctly rotating on my "Empty" plain axes

Tags: modifiers

The goal I am trying to achieve is simply have my cylinder rotate in a circular manner around  the empty plain axes. As I was following some tutorials online specific this one "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcB31AlYLAQ&ab_channel=digitalmonkeyschool", I can not understand why my array count is going towards the empty plain axes as seen below from the first picture. Instead what I am aiming to accomplished is the circular spread as seen in the second picture below. This may be a easy fix, but with my lack of experience I am having a hard time figure out the cause of the issue.

If you have any tips or solutions I would appreciate it thank you!

[image: Cylinder Object with Array Modifier]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out what was causing this dilemma. The reason I was facing this issue is that when I was scaling my cylinder I was doing so in object mode instead of edit mode. Thus blender was using the original size of the cylinder object to create the first copy of the cylinder, resulting the second copy to be scaled a lot smaller and on.